# App crashing, but not able to point it

Tags: ios

Getting app crash,
But not able to point it, added breakpoints for exception throw,
But that also not helped.

Here is the log i have got for crash,

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x42fa0004
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   UIFoundation                    0x372fe93e -[NSParagraphStyle _isSuitableForFastStringDrawingWithAlignment:lineBreakMode:tighteningFactorForTruncation:] + 542
1   UIFoundation                    0x373074a2 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 3286
2   UIFoundation                    0x373066fc -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:] + 144
3   UIKit                           0x2fe3185c -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 4436
4   UIKit                           0x2fe974ac -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 484
5   UIKit                           0x2fe972bc -[UILabel drawRect:] + 80
6   UIKit                           0x2fe97244 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 396
7   QuartzCore                      0x2f87567c -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 224
8   QuartzCore                      0x2f85e2ce CA::Layer::display_() + 510
9   QuartzCore                      0x2f842b18 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 196
10  QuartzCore                      0x2f8427dc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 20
11  QuartzCore                      0x2f8421c2 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 218
12  QuartzCore                      0x2f841fcc CA::Transaction::commit() + 320
13  QuartzCore                      0x2f83bed8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 52
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2c940012 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2c93d6f4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2c93daf6 __CFRunLoopRun + 910
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2c88ab2c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2c88a93e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
19  GraphicsServices                0x33c4104c GSEventRunModal + 132
20  UIKit                           0x2fe7cf1c UIApplicationMain + 1436
21  myapp                       0x0033c56c main (main.m:14)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a64faac start + 0
```

Comment: Do you have any custom drawing code? If yes please provide it.

Comment: Try to enable zombies .it will print the cause.

Comment: Yes actually i am using 1 library that plotting Graph. https://github.com/grevolution/SHLineGraphView

Comment: integrate  crashlatics to find out exactly where is the crash

Comment: @kiranpatil: how should that help when he already has a crash report? it doesn't help any more!

Comment: A breakpoint for exceptions won't help, since the crash is not caused by an exception but a memory management issue in your app.

Comment: Crashlatics give line numer & classs name where is actual crash

Comment: @kiranpatil: File names and line numbers are shown in the crash report already, see `21  myapp                       0x0033c56c main (main.m:14)`. If the crash doesn't happen with a stack trace from the app, no other crash reporting server can provide more information to what is already shown in this report. You would get the same crash report!

Answer (score 0):

Enable Zombie Objects

Select Target ----> Edit Scheme.. ----> Run [Diagnostics]

After that run the application. U will get know where your getting crash error.

[image]